# How to get all struct information created by program

Tags: anchor

In solidity, we can get all the struct information as an array and then do whatever we want. So in Solana, is there any way for us to do something like that? I find out that on the client side, we have to get all ATA created by program id and then get struct information following ATA. Is it correct and is it the only way to get all of that struct info?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `getProgramAccounts`, you can get all accounts that belong to a program, but this wouldn't tell you the ATAs created by a program, because they belong to the Token program, and not the calling program.

If you want to get all accounts created by a program, you must go through all transactions that contain that program, and see which accounts are created by inspecting each instruction in the transaction.